# Return only php data without html tags

Tags: php, html, shields.io

I am trying to create a custom shield from [shields.io](https://shields.io/). I tried the route where I create an endpoint with `json` but that won't work for me because of accessibility issues. I came up with a workaround where I call the shields.io link from my php side and then return that to an end point and then in return call that end point from my `md` README file in my `<img>` tags.

If I enter the url in the browser it works fine and I see the shield. If I try to use that url in my `<img>` tags in my README it doesn't work. I realized this is because I am returning extra `<html>` elements from my php. Here is my code:

php:

```
$router->get('/badge', function (AssetsManifestGateway $assetsManifestGateway) {
  $appVersion = $assetsManifestGateway->getAppVersion();

  $shield = file_get_contents("https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=". config('app.partner_code'). "_". config('app.env'). "&message=". $appVersion);
  return $shield; 
});
```

README:

```
<img src="http://<my url>/badge">
```

Response when accessing the url in my browser:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <extra content>
  </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

So I basically want to return only the `<svg>` part of that response. Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried with strip_tags?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't do the job.

Comment: try with html_entity_decode i hope it's work well.

Comment: No, still not. I think the url that is returned might be coming back "clean", without html, but perhaps the html is rendered somewhere else. But I have checked and can't see that it is.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to tell `php` to only send the response and not to generate any other html?

Comment: based on html_entity_decode you can get svg tag but in svg tag no data so that's why not getting anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209431/discussion-between-savaj-patel-and-corne).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your issue

By fetching the badge from shields.io (`file_get_contents`) and returning the svg badge, you actually cause your server to believe that what you are returning is html (see the `<svg></svg>` tags).

> I tried the route where I create an endpoint with `json` but that won't work for me because of accessibility issues.

I had similar issues a while ago. I resolved it by **creating a shields endpoint with php**.

That way you create JSON using php and let the shields server create a badge from it - instead of fetching and returning badges from shields.io (what you did).

### The code answering your question

I always use this function to create my badges, as abstraction seems very useful here:

```php
function createBadgeJson($label, $message, $color="green") {
  return "{
\"schemaVersion\": 1,
\"label\": \"$label\",
\"message\": \"$message\",
\"color\": \"$color\"
}";
}
```

To create the badge you tried to create above, put this into your php file:

```php
$appVersion = $assetsManifestGateway->getAppVersion();

echo createBadgeJson(config('app.partner_code'), $appVersion);
```

You can use your badge **in markdown** like this:

```
![your badge](https://img.shields.io/endpoint?url=https://your-endpoint-domain.com/your-badge-path)
```

Or **in HTML** by using the link format from above as an image source.

---

**Resources**

- I used this in my own shields endpoint ([finnmglas/shields](https://github.com/finnmglas/shields)). More details at https://shields.finnmglas.com.
- More about Shields enpoints: https://shields.io/endpoint